# Implement of BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME without Boost

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

There is the following code snippet:

```
template<typename ValueType>
ValueType any_cast(any & operand)
{
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME remove_reference<ValueType>::type nonref;


    nonref * result = any_cast<nonref>(&operand);
    if(!result)
        boost::throw_exception(bad_any_cast());

    // Attempt to avoid construction of a temporary object in cases when 
    // `ValueType` is not a reference. Example:
    // `static_cast<std::string>(*result);` 
    // which is equal to `std::string(*result);`
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::mpl::if_<
        boost::is_reference<ValueType>,
        ValueType,
        BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::add_reference<ValueType>::type
    >::type ref_type;

    return static_cast<ref_type>(*result);
}
```

Is there a possible to implement `BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME` without `Boost`? I can use only `C++11`.

Comment: What's wrong with the `typename` keyword?

Comment: @remyabel, could you give any example with `typename` for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a C++11 capable compiler, I find it highly unlikely that you require `BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME`. i.e., this is located in `include/boost/config/suffix.hpp`:

```
// BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME workaround ------------------------------------------//
//
// Some compilers don't support the use of `typename' for dependent
// types in deduced contexts, e.g.
//
//     template <class T> void f(T, typename T::type);
//                                  ^^^^^^^^
// Replace these declarations with:
//
//     template <class T> void f(T, BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME T::type);

#ifndef BOOST_NO_DEDUCED_TYPENAME
#  define BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME typename
#else
#  define BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME
#endif
```

Just use the `typename` keyword.